# Есть способ реализовать такое?

Tags: javascript

При создании объекта столкнулся с необходимостью для определения одного из полей внутри него воспользоваться другим, объявленным выше, полем:

```
obj = {
    a: [1, 2, 3],
    b: this.a.concat([4, 5, 6])
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: this.a is undefined

Нельзя как-нибудь это обойти?

Answer (score 2):

```js
obj = {
    a: [1, 2, 3],        
    b: function() { 
      return this.a.concat([4, 5, 6]);
    }
}

console.log(obj.b());
```

Но, кмк, это не лучший вариант и вообще лучше не искать способ *обойти*, а сделать сразу *по уму*. Иначе из костылей потом будет корабль собран, который потонет через N-ное время.

Comment: Как предложите "по уму" сделать? Предложения принимаются.

Comment: @nup я без понятия что вы там творите, что создаете, над чем работаете и какие задачи решаете в итоге. За неимением полной информации - говорить абстрактно не имеет смысла. Одно я знаю точно, желание сделать то, что в вопросе и возможность это сделать выглядят как лепка некоего костыля к чему-то бОльшему

Answer (score 0):

Eсли только так, не очень красиво, но

```js
obj = {
    a: [1, 2, 3]
}
obj['b'] = obj['a'].concat([4, 5, 6]);

console.log(obj);
```